# Make template for MV status maker

Tags: python, android, json, video-processing, adobe-premiere

I bought an android application from codecanyon. Its dynamic video status maker. Its author doesn't respond properly about how can we create custom template for it. I am sharing sample json file which I want to create. Please help if anyone has any idea.

link : https://codecanyon.net/item/lyrical-video-maker-mv-video-status-creator-whatsapp-status-saver-admob-fb-unity-ads-app-code/28895998

```
{
  "images":[
    {
      "name":"img_0.jpg",
      "w":540,
      "h":960,
      "prefix":[
        "-i"
      ],
      "postfix":[

      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"img_1.jpg",
      "w":540,
      "h":960,
      "prefix":[
        "-i"
      ],
      "postfix":[

      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"img_2.jpg",
      "w":540,
      "h":960,
      "prefix":[
        "-i"
      ],
      "postfix":[

      ]
    }
  ],
  "static_inputs":[
    {
      "name":"background_video.mp4",
      "prefix":[
        "-i"
      ],
      "postfix":[

      ]
    }
  ],
  "video":{
    "w":540,
    "h":960,
    "duration":30
  },
  "e":[],
  "m":[
    "-{pythoncomplex}"
  ],
  "r":["[3]split=2[color][alpha];[color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color];[alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[alpha];[color][alpha]{pythonmerge}[ovrly];[0]scale=540:960,setsar=1[0_scalled];[1]scale=540:960,setsar=1[1_scalled];[2]scale=540:960,setsar=1[2_scalled];[0_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*10.50:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=out:st=11.50:d=1[v0];[1_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*11.48:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=12.48:d=1[v1];[2_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*8.02:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=9.02:d=1[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[concatenated_video];[concatenated_video][ovrly]{pythono}=0:0[base_video];[base_video][4]{pythono}=enable='between(t,0,15)':x=30:y=30[watermarked_part1];[watermarked_part1][4]{pythono}=enable='between(t,15,30)':x=(main_w-{pythono}_w-30):y=30"],
  "i":["[3]split=2[color][alpha];[color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color];[alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[alpha];[color][alpha]{pythonmerge}[ovrly];[0]scale=540:960,setsar=1[0_scalled];[1]scale=540:960,setsar=1[1_scalled];[2]scale=540:960,setsar=1[2_scalled];[0_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*10.50:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=out:st=11.50:d=1[v0];[1_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*11.48:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=12.48:d=1[v1];[2_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.3,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*8.02:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=9.02:d=1[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[concatenated_video];[concatenated_video][ovrly]{pythono}=0:0[base_video];[base_video][4]{pythono}=enable='between(t,0,15)':x=30:y=30[watermarked_part1];[watermarked_part1][4]{pythono}=enable='between(t,15,30)':x=(main_w-{pythono}_w-30):y=30[final_video]"],
  "n":[],
  "g":[],
  "c":[],
  "o":[
    "-map",
    "[final_video]",
    "-map",
    "5:a"
  ],
  "d":[
    "-t",
    "30"
  ],
  "s":[],
  "layers": [
    {
      "ao": 0,
      "bm": 1,
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 1,
      "ip": 0,
      "ks": {
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 11,
          "k": 18.039
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 2,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 10,
          "k": 0
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 6,
          "k": [
            100,
            100,
            100
          ]
        }
      },
      "nm": "all",
      "op": 327,
      "refId": "image_0",
      "sr": 1,
      "st": 0,
      "ty": 2
    },
    {
      "ao": 0,
      "bm": 3,
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 2,
      "ip": 76,
      "ks": {
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 11,
          "k": 40
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 2,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 10,
          "k": 0
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 6,
          "k": [
            100,
            100,
            100
          ]
        }
      },
      "nm": "lvjing  all 3",
      "op": 327,
      "refId": "image_1",
      "sr": 1,
      "st": -8,
      "ty": 2
    },
    {
      "ao": 0,
      "bm": 13,
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 3,
      "ip": 76,
      "ks": {
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 11,
          "k": 50.196
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 2,
          "k": [
            270,
            480,
            0
          ]
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 10,
          "k": 0
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 0,
          "ix": 6,
          "k": [
            100,
            100,
            100
          ]
        }
      },
      "nm": "baohedu all 3",
      "op": 327,
      "refId": "image_2",
      "sr": 1,
      "st": -8,
      "ty": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you got idea?

Comment: anything you got on it?

Comment: I didn't get anything around this, seller also don't know how it works:(